# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in line

Tags: php, mysql

```
error_reporting( ~E_NOTICE );

require_once 'includes/connect5.php';

if(isset($_POST['btnsave']))
{
$reserveBy = $_POST['reserveBy'];
$bookId = $_POST['bookId'];// isbn
$bookTitle = $_POST['bookTitle'];// book name
$dateReserve = $_POST['dateReserve'];
if(empty($reserveBy)){
        $errMSG = "Please Enter Name.";
    }
else if(empty($bookId)){
        $errMSG = "Please Enter the BOok ISBN.";
    }
else if(empty($bookTitle)){
        $errMSG = "Please Enter the Title.";
    }
else
    {
        $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("INSERT INTO reservation(reserveBy,bookId,bookTitle,dateReserve,reserveExp) VALUES(:rrb, :risbn, :rbtit, now(), now() + INTERVAL 3 HOUR)");
        $stmt->bindParam(':rrb',$reserveBy);
        $stmt->bindParam(':risbn',$bookId);
        $stmt->bindParam(':rbtit',$bookTitle);

if($stmt->execute()) // this is the error line it points to this
        {
            $successMSG = "New Record Successfully Inserted ...";
            header("refresh:1;index1.php"); // redirects image view page after a seconds.
        }
        else
        {
            $errMSG = "error while inserting....";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I dont know why and how is has produced an error! It's pointing to the line:

```
if($stmt->execute())
```

It says:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in !
```

I dont understand why is it says number of bound variable does not match number of tokens even my input data is complete. I've searchd it to the internet but no one is similar to my problem.

Comment: Do you have other queries of this form that do work? What you have here seems to match up, there's three placeholders and three calls to `bindParam`.

Comment: thanks for the respond bro and sorry for inconvenient im newbie but im done solving this problem XD and thanks to you now i know that theres 3 calls to bindParam now im searching on it to undestand!

Comment: I have run your code here on PHP 5.4, mysql 5.5. It works correctly when all input values are present ;-/ i.e. I cannot reproduce your error. It may be worth adding your table SQL DDL statement to your question. Also some sample data. It may be worth checking that there are no invalid characters in your source code. I copied and pasted the code from the question. Maybe you should try that?